# 5v USB to 12v DC

Tags: usb, dc

I purchased a 5V USB to 12V DC step up converter cable from Amazon. My intention was to use a USB power bank to power a 12V DC monitor, but I’m running into a bit of a problem.

When testing the cable with another device (video transmission receiver) it works fine. My USB power bank outputs 5V 2A which is what the manufacturer of the converter cable recommends. The transmission receiver has a power consumption rating of <6W. The cable has a max output current of 0.6A. All works fine, no problems.

However, when trying to power my monitor it doesn’t seem happy. It powered up but made quite a worrying buzzing sound, so I turned it off straight away. The monitor has a 12V DC input and a power consumption rating of ≤18W.

Is it too high of a power consumption to work with the converter cable. Is there a workaround?

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Friendly note: Also cable length matters. The longer the cable the greater the losses.

Answer (score 2):

Power available from USB: 5 V * 2 A = 10 W.

The monitor needs up to 18 W.

So your monitor is likely asking for more power than the power bank can deliver.

> Is it too high of a power consumption to work with the converter cable.

The cable is not just a cable, it contains a DCDC converter. You did not include any specifications of that DCDC converter so it is impossible to judge if that DCDC converter can power the monitor.

The USB power bank can output a maximum 10 W which is lower than what the monitor might need.

**Maybe** a power bank with a higher output, in the order of 5 V, 4 A = 20 W would work but there are no guarantees. Also 4A is a bit much for a USB socket so using a single USB socket might simply not work.

You might want to consider using a power bank that can output 12 V, 2 A for the monitor.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, it makes sense now! I think the best option looking into it would be to go with USB C to 12V DC which can deliver up to 30W and of course the input would be much higher. Thanks again.

Comment: Can I send you a tip on PayPal for taking the time to help me out?

Comment: No we don't do that kind if thing here. If you insist, send the tip not to me but to Wikipedia as that's also a good source of knowledge: https://donate.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:LandingPage&country=NL&uselang=en&utm_medium=spontaneous&utm_source=fr-redir&utm_campaign=spontaneous